# php yii CGridView add column from different model

Tags: php, model, yii

The following I have in my admin.php view file, model is `Components`

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'components-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    /*'attributes'=>array(
        array(
         'label'=>'Asset Number',
                'value'=>"help",
        ),
    ),*/
    'columns'=>array(
        'component_id',

        'description',
        'version',
        'serial_no',
        'purchase_date',
        /*'disposal_date',

        'model',
        'nol',
        'manufacturer',
        'medium',
        */
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

I would like to add a extra column called asset number which is a field in another model `FixedAsset`. The two tables are linked together with their PK in the model `ComAsset`. What I ideally an trying to achieve is check each record in `Components` and see if it linked via the `component_id` if so then pull out the `original_asset_number` from `FixedAsset` using `fixed_asset_id` from `ComAsset`

relations

components - comasset = 1:1

fixedasset - comasset = 1:M

Comment: post the relations in  `Components` ,`ComAsset` and `FixedAsset`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the relationships are properly setup in the respective models you should be able to access the related information via `$data->relationshipName` in the `CGridView`. If I got the relationships right from your description the `value` part for this column should look something like this: `$data->comAsset->fixedAsset->name`.